# Case statement in join "AND" condition

Tags: mysql

I want to do something like the following, which doesn't work. The logic is: if a listing is still live, then get active user_favourite records, else get inactive ones.

```
select uf.* 
from user_favourite uf
join listings l on l.record_id = uf.listing_id
   AND 
     CASE WHEN l.status IN (0,1,5) THEN uf.active = 1
     ELSE uf.active = 0
     END CASE
where uf.listing_id = 13
```

What is the correct syntax for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be written as:

```
SELECT uf.* 
FROM user_favourite uf
JOIN listings l ON (
     l.record_id = uf.listing_id
     AND uf.active = IF(l.status IN (0,1,5), 1, 0)
)
WHERE uf.listing_id = 13
```

Also, the condition

```
uf.active = IF(l.status IN (0,1,5), 1, 0)
```

could be simplified as

```
uf.active = (l.status IN (0,1,5))
```

Or, if you want to keep the `CASE` statement

```
uf.active = CASE
    WHEN l.status IN (0,1,5) THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END
```